# CSS Compressor with @include support

Tags: css, compression

Is there any CSS compressor that supports the `@include` directive?

I have a bunch of css  files that have one main file and are linked via those `@include` directives. Now that I want to compress the CSS files I'm looking for a compression tool that supports that. **I'm not able to change the original files** not to use includes because those are centrally developed ones.

Comment: can you use php or something like that?

Comment: @antpaw: oh my! you created xCSS!! :D I realized now. Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

CSS frameworks like [**xCSS**](http://xcss.antpaw.org) can help you with `include` statements.

Comment: There is no way that I change the original files. So I think xCSS and all the other CSS frameworks won't help.

Comment: you don't need to change the files, just link the files inside the config.php (warning: xcss don't support @media or @include)